# Reshaping numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a numpy ndarray of 3D coordinates in the following form..

```
array([[  0.,   0.,  60.],
       [  0.,  40.,  60.],
       [  0.,  40.,   0.],
       ..., 
       [  6.,   0.,   2.],
       [  4.,   0.,   2.],
       [  2.,   0.,   2.]])
```

I'm trying to reshape it so that rather than a 1D vector of coordinates I get a 2D grid of coordinates.

The original array is of length 1302 which should allow me to reshape into a 21x62 arrangement.

I tried `coords_reshaped = np.ndarray.reshape(coords, (21,62))` but this spat out the error,

> ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

So what am I missing here?

Comment: "I'm trying to reshape it so that rather than a 1D vector of coordinates I get a 2D grid of coordinates." - you already *have* a 2D grid.

Comment: To clarify, I have a 1D vector of 3D coordinates

Comment: @user2357112 How? It's `1` row and `n` columns.

Comment: @DrBwts You should at least express what you want your output to be. Do you want `2`x`3` elements?

Comment: @JossieCalderon I mentioned it in the OP, 21x62

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
coords_reshaped = coords.reshape((21, 62, 3))
```